# Скрипт для поиска версий библиотеки в гитлаб репозитории

Tags: git, bash, gitlab

Необходимо в проектах репозитория найти версии определенной библиотеки в pom файлах проектов. И желательно получить список вида: "ссылка на проект: версия библиотеки".
Как я понимаю самое простое написать bash скрипт, но не знаю с чего начать, необходимо сначала куда то выгружать все pom файлы? Еще нашел такую тулзу https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA
Возможно уже существует еще какое то решение. Заранее благодарю за любую помощь

Comment: Если хотите написать скрипт - однозначна стоит начать с изучения документации по предполагаемому языку :)

Comment: Нужно декомпозировать задачу. 1. Скрипт проходится по списку проектов 2. В проекте ищет pom-файлы. Не знаю точно сколько их может быть. Допустим, он один 3. Из файла берется информация вида либа => версия, как-то записывается. Можно в файл, лучше - в БД, идеально для этого SQLite. 4. В конце скрипта из этого файла/БД строится вики-страница или что там вам нужно. Теперь про особенности. Скорее всего поиск будет по bare-репозиториям. git grep тут скорее всего бесполезен. Поэтому нужно сделать функцию для работы с bare.

Comment: `git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | grep -P '.*.pom$'` выведет список pom-файлов. Теперь нужно получить содержимое: `git show HEAD:путь-к-файлу-из.pom`. Это можно отправить на XML-парсилку и вытащить то что нужно. Я в принципе рассказал все основные моменты. Если есть вопросы по конкретному этапу - не знаете какую программу использовать, etc, уточните в вопросе

Comment: PS. Лучший вариант - добавить в pipeline GitLab команду, которая собственно получает всю необходимую инфу и складывает ее в БД/файл. Так будет проще

Comment: @TotalPusher да спасибо большое, вот тоже решил что в gitlab-ci добавлю скрипт, надеюсь получится ограничиться файлом, еще раз благодарю

Comment: @TotalPusher а подскажите пожалуйста, а при помощи регулярки искать нужную строку будет проблематичнее? Что то вроде grep -e "регулярное выражение"

Comment: Почему? В bare-репозиторий - через grep найти не получится, нет рабочего каталога. При запуске джобы гитлаба есть доступ к рабочим файлам, поэтому получится